# Error in If else if condition - missing keyword in SQL | Oracle |

Tags: sql, oracle

I am little bit stuck need to write the SQL if else if for below logic

As only basic knowledge on SQL

Below logic need to derived to SQL query

```
if depcost <> empcost and empcourseid in ('A','B') and empcd='LTR'
then

   empnfees=(empvar / empdar) * empcost

else if depcost <> empcost and empcourseid <> 'A'
then
     empnfees=empcost
else
     if empcd='XYZ'       
        empnfees=empcost
     else
        empnfees=depcost
```

**LOGIC :**

```
CASE WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid IN ('A', 'B') and empcd ='LTR'
     THEN (empvar / empdar) * empcost
     WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid <> 'A'
     THEN empcost
     ELSE
         CASE 
              when empcd='XYZ'
              then empcost
         else
              depcost
  
     END as EMPVAR
```

The above code is throwing me error : missing keyword
How to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use two cases but only one end. You need another end here:

```
CASE WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid IN ('A', 'B') and empcd ='LTR'
     THEN (empvar / empdar) * empcost
     WHEN depcost <> empcost AND empcourseid <> 'A'
     THEN empcost
     ELSE
         CASE
              when empcd='XYZ'
              then empcost
         ELSE
              depcost
         END --------------- missing end

     END as EMPVAR
```

Hope I helped you

Comment: Thanks bro it work like charm

Comment: @xawefog, please accept the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that solved your problem so people know your problem is solved